# ¿Cómo agregar NameSpace a elemento XML?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

Firmo un documento XML con Xades-Epes pero  debo agregar NameSpace al elemento Signature ¿Cómo lo hago?

Actualmente el elemento tiene esta estructura:

```
<Signature Id="SignatureId">
```

y nesecito que se vea asi:

```
<ds:Signature Id="SignatureId" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
 XadesSignedXml signedXml = new XadesSignedXml(xmlDoc);
            signedXml.Signature.Id = "SignatureId";
```

Este es el XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FacturaElectronica xmlns="https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Clave>1234</Clave>
    <NumeroConsecutivo>123456789</NumeroConsecutivo>
    <FechaEmision>2017-09-21T20:00:56-04:00</FechaEmision>
    <Emisor>
        <Nombre>Hacienda CR</Nombre>
        <Identificacion>
            <Tipo>01</Tipo>
            <Numero>999</Numero>
        </Identificacion>
        <NombreComercial>Hacienda CR SRL</NombreComercial>
        <Ubicacion>
            <Provincia>Valencia</Provincia>
            <Canton>S/Canton</Canton>
            <Distrito>Carabobo</Distrito>
            <Barrio>DonBosco</Barrio>
            <OtrasSenas>107-35</OtrasSenas>
        </Ubicacion>
        <Telefono>
            <CodigoPais>+058</CodigoPais>
            <NumTelefono>02418317261</NumTelefono>
        </Telefono>
        <Fax>
            <CodigoPais>+058</CodigoPais>
            <NumTelefono>04127568744</NumTelefono>
        </Fax>
        <CorreoElectronico>haciendacr@gmail.com</CorreoElectronico>
    </Emisor>
    <Receptor>
        <Nombre>Nombre Cliente Apellido Cliente</Nombre>
        <Identificacion>
            <Tipo>02</Tipo>
            <Numero>04145558889</Numero>
        </Identificacion>
        <IdentificacionExtranjero>E</IdentificacionExtranjero>
        <NombreComercial>Nombre ClienteCA</NombreComercial>
        <Ubicacion>
            <Provincia>Valencia</Provincia>
            <Canton>S/Canton</Canton>
            <Distrito>Carabobo</Distrito>
            <Barrio>DonBosco</Barrio>
            <OtrasSenas>107-35</OtrasSenas>
        </Ubicacion>
        <Telefono>
            <CodigoPais>+058</CodigoPais>
            <NumTelefono>02418317261</NumTelefono>
        </Telefono>
        <Fax>
            <CodigoPais>+058</CodigoPais>
            <NumTelefono>02418317261</NumTelefono>
        </Fax>
        <CorreoElectronico>comprador@gmail.com</CorreoElectronico>
    </Receptor>
    <CondicionVenta>01</CondicionVenta>
    <PlazoCredito>3 meses</PlazoCredito>
    <MedioPago>01</MedioPago>
    <DetalleServicio>
        <LineaDetalle>
            <NumeroLinea>1000</NumeroLinea>
            <Codigo>
                <Tipo>01</Tipo>
                <Codigo>666</Codigo>
            </Codigo>
            <Cantidad>19.9</Cantidad>
            <UnidadMedida>kg</UnidadMedida>
            <UnidadMedidaComercial>KG</UnidadMedidaComercial>
            <Detalle>kilogramo</Detalle>
            <PrecioUnitario>19.9</PrecioUnitario>
            <MontoTotal>19.9</MontoTotal>
            <MontoDescuento>19.9</MontoDescuento>
            <NaturalezaDescuento>descuento</NaturalezaDescuento>
            <SubTotal>19.9</SubTotal>
            <Impuesto>
                <Codigo>01</Codigo>
                <Tarifa>19.9</Tarifa>
                <Monto>19.9</Monto>
                <Exoneracion>
                    <TipoDocumento>01</TipoDocumento>
                    <NumeroDocumento>1001</NumeroDocumento>
                    <NombreInstitucion>1002</NombreInstitucion>
                    <FechaEmision>2017-09-21T20:00:56-04:00</FechaEmision>
                    <MontoImpuesto>19.9</MontoImpuesto>
                    <PorcentajeCompra>100</PorcentajeCompra>
                </Exoneracion>
            </Impuesto>
            <MontoTotalLinea>19.9</MontoTotalLinea>
        </LineaDetalle>
    </DetalleServicio>
    <ResumenFactura>
        <CodigoMoneda>AED</CodigoMoneda>
        <TipoCambio>19.9</TipoCambio>
        <TotalServGravados>19.9</TotalServGravados>
        <TotalServExentos>19.9</TotalServExentos>
        <TotalMercanciasGravadas>19.9</TotalMercanciasGravadas>
        <TotalMercanciasExentas>19.9</TotalMercanciasExentas>
        <TotalGravado>19.9</TotalGravado>
        <TotalExento>19.9</TotalExento>
        <TotalVenta>19.9</TotalVenta>
        <TotalDescuentos>19.9</TotalDescuentos>
        <TotalVentaNeta>19.9</TotalVentaNeta>
        <TotalImpuesto>19.9</TotalImpuesto>
        <TotalComprobante>19.9</TotalComprobante>
    </ResumenFactura>
    <InformacionReferencia>
        <TipoDoc>01</TipoDoc>
        <Numero>12345678</Numero>
        <FechaEmision>2017-09-21T20:00:56-04:00</FechaEmision>
        <Codigo>01</Codigo>
        <Razon>SnRazon</Razon>
    </InformacionReferencia>
    <Normativa>
        <NumeroResolucion>000123</NumeroResolucion>
        <FechaResolucion>2017-09-22T11:57:56+11:57</FechaResolucion>
    </Normativa>
    <Otros>
        <OtroTexto codigo="AS345">AS21</OtroTexto>
        <OtroContenido codigo="gdfgdfg"/>
    </Otros>
    <Signature Id="SignatureId">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference Type="http://www.gzs.si/shemas/eslog/racun/1.5#Racun" URI="">
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue>IQoCIymW+aMQNZRmShrCdiQO64E=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
            <Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.1.1#SignedProperties" URI="">
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue>IQoCIymW+aMQNZRmShrCdiQO64E=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>GCIgulzQ+aUIXieqQiFsZLGOEtHn/USwz1Gx5DGKyorCPusDkJVH4mJWR0ErfxqoYQaEW7fPs90rG2KQeK7ricVEn2VrQONiiVOcSVFIkmXx4P54oDJrwdvTu4Zvz6l3AtXK0LvkugUcPbNDj4V6LlmHA5IYaiEDZP+MtDKknt0=</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
        <Object>
            <xds:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xds="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="#SignatureId">
                <xds:SignedProperties Id="SignedPropertiesId">
                    <xds:SignedSignatureProperties>
                        <xds:SigningTime>2017-09-22T07:57:58.931Z</xds:SigningTime>
                        <xds:SigningCertificate>
                            <xds:Cert>
                                <xds:CertDigest>
                                    <xds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                    <xds:DigestValue>79OUfDRZuvRQ3VvHWG9qvQXIgHHLIMmzFerskdjQffA=</xds:DigestValue>
                                </xds:CertDigest>
                                <xds:IssuerSerial>
                                    <ds:X509IssuerName xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">CN=EMCSERVER\EfrainMejiasC</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">310C4035DEBD6EA146D0A91CC5055CDD</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                </xds:IssuerSerial>
                            </xds:Cert>
                        </xds:SigningCertificate>
                    </xds:SignedSignatureProperties>
                </xds:SignedProperties>
            </xds:QualifyingProperties>
        </Object>
    </Signature>
</FacturaElectronica>
```

Comment: Revisa en tu XML si tienes establecido un alias al espacio de nombres http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig# a nivel global. Si es así, no te haría falta establecerlo en el elemento Signatura. Verifica que tu XML es correcto validando el esquema.

Comment: Hola Sergio Parra Guerra...No tiene establecido el espacio de nombre a nivel global ¿Como lo hago?

Comment: Puedes pasar un ejemplo de tu XML firmado?

Comment: Listo ya edite el post

Comment: Hola. Cómo tienes definida tu clase Signature? Porque podrías establecer allí como un atributo de serialización ese namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los atributos que mencionas se conocen como namespace

[Managing Namespaces in an XML Document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/managing-namespaces-in-an-xml-document)

[Adding namespaces to XmlDocument using XmlNamespaceManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659248/adding-namespaces-to-xmldocument-using-xmlnamespacemanager)

en el ejemplo veras que podrias usar

```
var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
```

lo que si recomendaria es que evalues usar `linq to xml` ya que es mucho mas practico

[How to: Create a Document with Namespaces (C#) (LINQ to XML)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-create-a-document-with-namespaces-linq-to-xml)

Comment: Hola Leandro. En vez de poner enlace solo, intenta desarrollar la respuesta. Un saludo ^^

Comment: pero puse un ejemplo en codigo de como usar las clases para generar un nameapace, cuanto mas se necesita desarrollar ? necesitas que escriba un libro de 200 paginas. Si quieres copio el texto de los link y lo pego como respuesta

Comment: y.. yo creo que por lo menos explicar todos esos links que apuntan a sitios en ingles. Si la respuesta requiere un libro, entonces la pregunta es muy amplia. Criticamos a Usuarios con Baja reputacion por respuestas de este estilo.

Comment: Los link son a modo de referencia sobre el tema que menciono, podria simplemente decirle que se soluciona definiendo namespace y con el ejemplo, pero lo link son un complemento para que no busque el tema incorrectamente. La explicacion de los links esta en el ejemplo. El ultimo es solo una sugerencia, no amplio porque no creo que aplique linq. Ademas desde cuando ingles es un problema? estuvimos año con StackOverflow solo en ingles para ahora volverse purista por unos links de referencia.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini FYI: [Cómo: Crear un documento con espacios de nombres (C#) (LINQ to XML)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ES-ES/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-create-a-document-with-namespaces-linq-to-xml). Es solo ser considerados con personas que no dominan el inglés.

Comment: @Davlio genial, gracias, no me di cuenta de cambiarle la cultura, a veces la doc oficial solo esta en ingles, pero en este caso esta bueno si puede traducirse